# eXist-db XSL-FO – hyphenation and settings

Tags: xsl-fo, exist-db

I am running eXist on a headless virtual Ubuntu sever. Interesting was the XSL-FO module **was** enabled by default, maybe because I had it installed on the server before installing eXist.

I use configuration file residing inside the app’s collection. Interesting is it uses (and only allows) system paths and it is not possible to use resources from within the collection (e.g. I have tried to load fonts and point at them from the config but that did not work—I had to use it as it was when I used it without eXist. Everything works but the hyphenation. Without eXist, hyphenation works too.

```
<fop version="1.0">
    <hyphenation-base>/home/honza/.fop/hyph</hyphenation-base>
    <hyphenation-pattern lang="cs" country="CZ">cs</hyphenation-pattern>
    <renderers>
        <renderer mime="application/pdf">
            <fonts>
                <font kerning="yes" embed-url="/home/honza/.fonts/libertine/LinLibertine_Rah.ttf" embedding-mode="subset">
                    <font-triplet name="LinLibertine" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
                </font>
                <font kerning="yes" embed-url="/home/honza/.fonts/libertine/LinLibertine_RIah.ttf" embedding-mode="subset">
                    <font-triplet name="LinLibertine" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
                </font>
                <font kerning="yes" embed-url="/home/honza/.fonts/libertine/LinLibertine_RBah.ttf" embedding-mode="subset">
                    <font-triplet name="LinLibertine" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
                </font>
                <font kerning="yes" embed-url="/home/honza/.fonts/libertine/LinLibertine_RBIah.ttf" embedding-mode="subset">
                    <font-triplet name="LinLibertine" style="italic" weight="bold"/>
                </font>
                <font kerning="yes" embed-url="/home/honza/.fonts/libertine/LinBiolinum_Rah.ttf" embedding-mode="subset">
                    <font-triplet name="LinBiolinum" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
                </font>
                <font kerning="yes" embed-url="/home/honza/.fonts/libertine/LinBiolinum_RIah.ttf" embedding-mode="subset">
                    <font-triplet name="LinBiolinum" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
                </font>
                <font kerning="yes" embed-url="/home/honza/.fonts/libertine/LinBiolinum_RBah.ttf" embedding-mode="subset">
                    <font-triplet name="LinBiolinum" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
                </font>
            </fonts>
        </renderer>
    </renderers>
</fop>
```

I know the `hyphenation-base` is the right place where to start but can’t figure out whether it should be in some special way set because of the eXist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're calling FOP from within eXist, you need to store your hyphenation jar (`fop-hyph.jar`) in `$EXIST_HOME/extensions/modules/lib/`, alongside `fop.jar`.  Then you shouldn't need the `<hyphenation-base>` property at all in your `fop.conf` file - the `<hyphenation-pattern>` should suffice.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Solved!

Comment: Still testing, the problem could be (and I will report that in the mail-list) if FOP is called from outside of the whole eXist’s installation. If so, the `<hyphenation-base>` is still needed. Without that it does not hyphenate :(